# Docker not found in Gitlab CI

Tags: docker, gitlab, aws-cdk, cicd

am trying to follow this [link](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/apn/building-cross-account-deployment-in-gitlab-pipelines-using-aws-cdk/) to deploy using `Gitlab CI` and `CDK`

my `.gitlab-ci.yml` looks like below ...

```
image: node:18-alpine    
cache:
  paths:
  - cdk/node_modules/

stages:
- build
- deploy

build:
  stage: build
  script:
    - cd cdk
    - npm install

deploy:
  stage: deploy
  services:
    - name: docker
  variables:
    ENV: "dev"
    AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: $AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
    AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: $AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
    CDK_DEPLOY_ACCOUNT: $SANDBOX_ACCOUNT_ID
    CDK_DEFAULT_ACCOUNT: $SANDBOX_ACCOUNT_ID
    CDK_DEPLOY_REGION: $AWS_DEFAULT_REGION
  before_script:
  - npm install -g aws-cdk@latest
  - cdk --version
  script:
    - docker --version
    - cd cdk && cdk deploy ExpressAppStack --require-approval never --verbose
```

but it keeps failing at `deploy` with

```
npm install -g aws-cdk@latest
added 1 package in 1s
$ cdk --version
2.130.0 (build bd6e5ee)
$ docker --version
/bin/sh: eval: line 155: docker: not found
Cleaning up project directory and file based variables
00:00
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 127
```

I expected the YML to work as the one mentioned in AWS tutorial, can some one explain how and why to fix this ?

Comment: The link you provided doesn't use `docker` at all. It can't find docker because docker is not included in the `image:` you are using and you did not install it as part of your job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can install required dependencies for the alpine based image as part of a before_script or similar:

```
before_script:
  - apk add docker-cli bash
```

You might also need to specify DOCKER_HOST=tcp://docker:2375 to make it actually target your sidecar service.

bash is needed if you use esbuild for building lambdas and similar via CDK.

You might also wanna consider creating this base image for repeated use instead of installing dependencies over and over again.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the `docker` executable is not found in the CI runner machine's paths to executable commands.

Every job in your gitlab ci file will run in a docker container, as specified by the `image` keyword. At the top of your file you specified `image: node:18-alpine` which means all your jobs will run using that image. That means that the docker container executing your script will only have access to the executables that the image has pre-configured with it. And in your case, `node:18-alpine` does not have the docker cli installed.

You can reproduce this behavior locally using a docker container.

```
❯ docker run --rm -it --entrypoint /bin/sh node:18-alpine docker --version
/bin/sh: can't open 'docker': No such file or directory
```

If you switch your image to be something that *has* the docker cli installed, you'll be able to access it within your script. For example, we can see with the `docker:25.0.3-dind` image.

```
❯ docker run --rm -it docker:25.0.3-dind docker --version
Docker version 25.0.3, build 4debf41
```

This particular image is just an example. You'll want to ensure that the particular image you choose to run your script with has all the necessary dependencies for your deployment process. It's entirely possible that no such off-the-shelf image has everything you need. In which case you can either build a custom image, or install what you need within your script itself. For example, you might choose to modify your script to simply install the docker CLI before executing the rest of the script steps.

```yaml
script:
- # install docker CLI
- # run your deployment steps
```